# Wordpress visit all external links on page when I click any 1 link.

Tags: wordpress, external, commission-junction, cj

I have developed an affiliate website in wordpress.  My site contains list of godaddy domains in table. All links are affiliated links in table.

Problem is when I click on any link from table in wordpress website then at CJ.com it counts all the link as a click in the list.

For eg. I have 405 domains in a list of table, when I click on any 1 link than at CJ.com it shows 406 clicks.

I have even tried this on fresh wordpress installation.

Here is the few example of source code:

```
<table class="footable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <thead>  <tr> <th width="93px">Domain Name</th> <th width="50">Price</th> <th width="93">Auction End Time</th> <th width="93">Sale Type</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td><a href="http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-8186857-10497118-1476294381000?url=https://in.auctions.godaddy.com/trpItemListing.aspx?miid=205703908" target="new">x1r.biz</a></td> <td>$5</td> <td>11-04-16 1:52</td> <td>Buy Now</td> </tr> </tbody>  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your href target attribute to `target="_blank"` and it's smart to add `rel="nofollow"` so Google will not index the Godaddy pages under your name.

Code:

```
<table class="footable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
<thead>  
    <tr> 
        <th width="93px">Domain Name</th> 
        <th width="50">Price</th> 
        <th width="93">Auction End Time</th> 
        <th width="93">Sale Type</th> 
    </tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
    <tr> 
        <td><a href="http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-8186857-10497118-1476294381000?url=https://in.auctions.godaddy.com/trpItemListing.aspx?miid=205703908" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">x1r.biz</a></td> 
        <td>$5</td> 
        <td>11-04-16 1:52</td> 
        <td>Buy Now</td> 
    </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: Also a good practice to add `"noopener noreferrer"` to your `rel` attributes as well: https://dev.to/ben/the-targetblank-vulnerability-by-example

Comment: I did this but it didn't helped. I have added 11 domains in table and clicked on 1 link and at cj.com it counted 12 clicks.

Comment: also I would like to update that there is no issue with same list in opencart website.

Comment: How are you counting the clicks?